# Saving bitmap to a file resulting in black image

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I used the API sample from android for drawing on a view responding to touch events. basically what it does is that everytime I touch the screen, it draws a circle on top of what I have there (so draws a circle with transparent background resulting in looking like as if the contents were preserved)

Now the issue is when I try to save it as an image. I tried both JPG and PNG and I get black picture. Somehow it is making all the transparent stuffs appear black I guess.

Is there ANY way I can have this bitmap saved as an image (preferrebly JPG)? When you look at the image itself it does not have transperency at all.

Thank you

Code added as requested

I initialize the view as follow

```
 @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            int curW = mBitmap != null ? mBitmap.getWidth() : 0;
            int curH = mBitmap != null ? mBitmap.getHeight() : 0;
            if (curW >= w && curH >= h) {
                return;
            }

            if (curW < w) curW = w;
            if (curH < h) curH = h;

            Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(curW, curH, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas();
            newCanvas.setBitmap(newBitmap);
            if (mBitmap != null) {
                newCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
            }
            mBitmap = newBitmap;
            mCanvas = newCanvas;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            if (mBitmap != null) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
            }
        }
```

I paint the view as follow

```
void paintmycolor(float x, float y, float major, float minor){
mPaint.setColor(myDrawColor);
mPaint.setAlpha(Math.min((int) (pressure * 128), 255));
 canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
 RectF mReusableOvalRect = new RectF();
            canvas.rotate((float) (orientation * 180 / Math.PI), x, y);
            mReusableOvalRect.left = x - minor / 2;
            mReusableOvalRect.right = x + minor / 2;
            mReusableOvalRect.top = y - major / 2;
            mReusableOvalRect.bottom = y + major / 2;
            canvas.drawOval(mReusableOvalRect, paint);
            canvas.restore();
}
```

I save as follows
 public File saveBitmap() throws IOException {

```
        File path=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DCIM);
        File myDirectory = new File(path,mContext.getString(R.string.app_name));
        if(!myDirectory.exists()){
            myDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
        File output;
        do {
            int rand = new Random().nextInt();
            output = new File(myDirectory,rand+".jpg");
        }while(output.exists());

        BufferedOutputStream ous = null;
        try {
            ous=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output));
            mBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ous);
            ous.flush();
            ous.close();
            return output;

        } finally {
            if (ous!=null) {
                try {
                    ous.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("closing", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you drawing your circle user view ...??please share your draw circle for better understandings

Comment: show some code. Some gotchas: 1) JPGs, don't support transparency, so you will get a black background. And if your circle is black, well you won't be able to find it. 2) Are you using a SurfaceView? Or are you using Canvas? SurfaceView actually draws a black image into the canvas and if you use canvas to capture a bitmap, the SurfaceView layer has not been rendered yet so your bitmap will be black.

Comment: I added the code that is relevent. It is a normal View that  I am extending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. When you create a bitmap, although it shows it as white but it is actually transparent background. That's why I get black

Comment: After you create a bitmap, color it all white so you dont end up with trasnprency

Comment: @Snake, Dude! I need image with Transparency just like Stickers in WhatsApp. How to solve then?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for that to retain the Transparency without changing the color to white(may be you would use it with non-white background layout):

When creating a bitmap to save it in the memory, and **BEFORE** saving it assign the following condition to it:

```
mBitmap.setHasAlpha(true);
```

This will make the image retain its transparency while being on the device, and that will result to an image with transparency while retrieving it back from the memory.

After all, don't forget to save it as PNG:

```
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, ous);
```