# Bitmap loses transparency when it's saved

Tags: android, bitmap, save, transparency

i have a problem when i'm trying to save a bitmap to the external picture directory. When i use the Bitmap.compress function to save it, the bitmap loses its transparency and makes the background black. But when i pass the bitmap to a imageview and show it in the activity it looks fine and has transparency. Only when i try to save it, then transparency turns black.

I have to say, that im using two bitmaps and porterduff mode the draw a path on a bitmap and show only the picture in the drawn path, and all other pixels should be cut off or transparent.

So here's the function for creating a path bitmap:

```
private void createPathBitmap(RectF rect, Bitmap bitmap, Path path) {
    RectF tmpRect = new RectF(rect);
    Bitmap src = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, (int) tmpRect.left, (int) tmpRect.top, (int) tmpRect.width(), (int) tmpRect.height());
    Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dst);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(mDisplayDensity * SnippetLayer.PATH_DIAMETER);
    path.offset(-rect.left, -rect.top);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    RectF srcRect = new RectF(0, 0, rect.width(), rect.height());
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, null, srcRect, paint);
    BitmapManager.sBitmapSnippet = dst;
}
```

And here's the method for saving that bitmap to external storage:

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH_mm_ss_dd_MM_yyyy");
        File snippetFile = new File(picDir, fileName+"_"+dateFormat.format(new Date())+".png");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(snippetFile);
            BitmapManager.sBitmapSnippet.setHasAlpha(true);
            BitmapManager.sBitmapSnippet.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The picture is shown only in the path, and the rest of the bounding box is black and not transparent.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: same problem. Did u solve it?

Comment: Hi, no unfortunately not, but I figured out, that those images have transparent background when i copy them on my pc and open a image viewer program...so maybe Android's photo app makes it a black background...

Comment: @sNore Hey I am experiencing same problem. Did you solved it?

Comment: @Nitesh Khatri I have no solution for that sorry.

Comment: Try this:
bitmap.setHasAlpha(true);

Comment: Hey I am experiencing same problem. Did you solved it?

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398133/saving-bitmap-to-a-file-resulting-in-black-image

Answer (score 11):

I'm using compress() method to write bitmap into output stream:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

It is important to use PNG format. JPEG transforms my transparent background into black color.

Comment: this may be work in eclips but android studio lose the transparancy

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why exactly does it lose transparency, but I had the same problem. All you have to do is to change

`BitmapManager.sBitmapSnippet.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);`

to

`BitmapManager.sBitmapSnippet.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, fileOutputStream);`.

This will compress the bitmap with full quality, but containing transparent regions.

Comment: The quality data is misleading, see Javadoc: ```@param quality Hint to the compressor, 0-100. 0 meaning compress for small size, 100 meaning compress for max quality. Some formats, like PNG which is lossless, will ignore the quality setting```

Answer (score 0):

Don't loose transparency by this small snippet

Here Problem is you save image in .JPEG so JPEG take black background as transparent so we will save in .PNG so definitely get transparent Image

```java
    private void saveImage(Bitmap data, View view) {
        File createFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Magic PhotoShoot");
        if (!createFolder.exists())
            createFolder.mkdir();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        File saveImage = new File(createFolder, "Photoshoot_" + strDate + ".png");
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveImage);
            data.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Snackbar.make(view, "Saved to PhotoShoot successfully", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isSave = true;
            Glob.savedImage = saveImage.getAbsolutePath();
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), saveImage.getAbsolutePath(), saveImage.getName(), saveImage.getName());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "File not found", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Error while saving image", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[JPEG does not support transparency. JPEG's lossy compression also suffers from generation loss, where repeatedly decoding and re-encoding an image to save it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)

Use **PNG extension** file format for storing images in storage

**In Kotlin:**

Here is bitmap which is used for compression and saving into storage using file path

```
val file=File(outputImagePath)
    var fout: OutputStream? = null
                fout = FileOutputStream(file)
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fout)
                fout.flush()
                fout.close()`
```

**In Java:**

Here is bitmap which is used for compression and saving into storage using file path

```
File imageFile = new File(outputImagePath);
            OutputStream fout = null;
            fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fout);
            fout.flush();
            fout.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG or Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP. If you want to get less size image. you should use Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP like me.

[image]